# Finding standard deviation from normal distribution given mean and probability x is between specific interval

Tags: normal-distribution

In general how can one compute the standard deviation of the normal distribution when the mean and the following is given:
$$ P(x_1 < x < x_2) = \alpha$$

I already tried a lot of things but can't figure it out. 
Is there enough information to solve this probem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $x_1, x_2, \alpha, \mu$ (i.e. the mean), solve $$\alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\exp\left(-\frac 1 2 \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$
for $\sigma$. However, there exists no closed-form solution. That is, the solution has to be found numerically. The **R** code below examplifies the procedure:

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 10
mu = 5
alpha = 0.5

uniroot(
  function(sigma) alpha - pnorm(x2, mu, sigma) + pnorm(x1, mu, sigma), 
  lower = 0, upper = 1e6
)
```

Result: 6.652907. Indeed, $$P(1\leq X \leq 10) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\cdot6.652907^2}}\int_{1}^{10}\exp\left(-\frac 1 2 \frac{(x - 5)^2}{6.652907^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx  = 0.4999997 \approx 0.5 = \alpha.$$

Comment: Thanks, I already thought there would be no other approach than solve the integral via computer assistance

Answer (score 1):

If the mean and standard deviation are denoted by $\mu$ and $\sigma$ respectively, then
$$\alpha = P(x_1 < X < x_2) = P\left(\frac{x_1-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{x_2 - \mu}{\sigma}\right).$$
Note that $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ is a standard normal random variable, so if you knew $\sigma$ the right-hand side could be computed from a normal table or a computer.

If the mean $\mu$ is between $x_1$ and $x_2$, then the right-hand side decreases continuously from $1$ to $0$ as $\sigma \to \infty$, so there is some value of $\sigma$ such that the probability equals $\alpha$. Otherwise the situation is more complicated.

Comment: So there really is no "easy" solution, we will have to guess and find a approximately value of $\sigma$  I guess?

Comment: @areobe Right, because the there isn't a closed form of the normal CDF. Note that a solution may not even exist if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both larger (or both smaller) than the mean.